# Adding class to featured image

Tags: custom-post-types, images, twitter-bootstrap, post-class

I have specified a loop to show featured images for my custom post type and wish to add a  img-responsive class from bootstrap to my featured image.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Code:

```
<div class="home-featured-img">
    <?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
        the_post_thumbnail(); // show featured image
    } 
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add custom class to post thumbnails. [the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) accepts array of attribute `$attr` where you can specify image class.

So your code will be.

```
<div class="home-featured-img">
    <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
            the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class'  => 'responsive-class' ) ); // show featured image
        } 
    ?>
</div>
```

In above code, `responsive-class` is the custom class I have added, you can change it as you require.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of [`the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) is `$attr`, which you can add classes to. One note is that you will be overriding the default classes, so you will need to add them in as well. The default is `attachment-$size`, which is why I added `attachment-post-thumbnail` in my example.

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail', array(
    'class' => 'attachment-post-thumbnail my-custom-class'
) );
```